# Not getting title of my website when I share it on whatsapp

Tags: html, whatsapp

Whenever I share my website through whatsapp, I am not able to see title of my website. Instead of title, **A** appears.
[How it looks like on whatsapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZBfZ.png)

Here is my code.

```
 <meta name="description" content="Advice and Review">
 <meta property="og:title" content="A&R — Advice & Review" />
 <meta property="og:description" content="Easy to find which device you want" />
 <meta property="og:url" content="https://aandrtest4lakshit.netlify.app/" />
 <meta property="og:image" content="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/761564515878830111/879949532845178940/Favicon.png" />
 <meta property="og:type" content="Shopping" />
 <meta property="og:locale" content="en_GB" />
 <title>A&R — Advice & Review</title>`
```

I want to tell that This is perfectly working on discord...

[How it looks like on discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ22d.png)

**Edit**: I just realized that this problem is only with whatsapp web...

Comment: Hey, I tried https://aandrtest4lakshit.netlify.app/ url in whatsapp. it is working fine for me. It is showing A&R — Advice & Review.

Comment: You could try escaping your `&` as `&amp;`. I assume WhatsApp uses some kind of OS dependant function to detect the title, so some might geht confused by the `&`

Comment: Aram Becker, thanks a lot for your suggestion..... I did as you told...I replaced both ‘&’ with ‘&amp;’ .....But unfortunately now also its not working.....now also...I am still getting that **A** instead of the title....
 ...But I want to tell that this is perfectly working on discord.

Comment: It will take a little time for the caches to clear. It will probably be fixed if you wait a little time--I suggest you work on something else for now and check back later. If your site is on Cloudflare or a similar service, you can try flushing the cache from there to speed up the process.

Comment: try on different devices.

Comment: ok I will try ...

Comment: Amirreza, thanks a lot.....I just realized that this problem is only with whatsapp web...its working perfectly on my mobile whatsapp...

Comment: this is a great first question Lakshit, welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for communicating nicely too. Also, great shout on escaping the ampersand @AramBecker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend just restarting your WhatsApp (by closing the app) and also saving your code.

If that doesn’t work, try using the ampersand (&) as a character code. (Replace both ‘`&`’ with ‘`&amp;`’). This is either because WhatsApp doesn’t support these characters without the character code or because WhatsApp is expecting another character code to follow your `&`.

EDIT: website in iMessage:
[image]

Comment: Matthias, thanks a lot for your suggestion..... I did as you told...I replaced both ‘&’ with ‘&amp;’ .....But unfortunately now also its not working.....I also tried restarting whatsapp.....But now also...I am still getting that **A** instead of the title....

Comment: @LakshitBansal I feel like WhatsApp is being a bit slow to update, or has something against the ampersand. It works fine in iMessage for me. (See the updated post above)

Comment: Yea the only problem is with whatsapp......It works fine with discord too